# How do I stop text from showing / flowing outside of an <h3> tag?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm not sure why, but I get this text showing / flowing outside of the `<h3>` tag. I thought it was something to do with floats, but I have tried all the solutions I know to fix it and they haven't worked.

Here is jsfiddle (I'm in Safari): http://jsfiddle.net/BJCkv/1/

**HTML :**

```
<div id="header-container">
    <div class="wrapper"> <!-- has width of 940px; and aligned in middle -->
        <h1>PCSA - TRAINING</h1>
        <h3>Security Architecture</h3> <!-- This is the problem text -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
#header-container {
    height: 84px;
    line-height: 84px;
    background-color: #e0dfd9;
    background-image: url(../img/header.png);
    border-top: 1px solid #ccccc7;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccccc7;
}
#header-container .wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#header-container h1 {
    color: #b8622b;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 38px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #f7f7f5;
    font-weight: 600;
    float: left;
    background: red;
}
#header-container h3 {
    color: #a5a5a4;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    padding: 3px 0 3px 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    height: 30px;
    border-left: 1px solid #a5a5a4;
    background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: its because of the height you set to the h3;

Comment: @Eric Yea but I need that height there, I assumed text would be inside of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `replace height: 30px;` with `line-height: 30px;` That should solve the problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/BJCkv/7/

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the line-height for the `h3` element: Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BJCkv/5/

```
#header-container h3 {
    line-height: 30px; /* add this */
    color: #a5a5a4;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    padding: 3px 0 3px 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    height: 30px;
    border-left: 1px solid #a5a5a4;

    background: yellow;
}
```